# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/jcraft/jsch/Session.setDaemonThread(Z)V

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

i'm using the JSch jar to implement SFTP communication.
downloaded the JSch and using the vfs2 jar.

when running the code on weblogic server - it runs perfectly.

when running it on websphere application server (same code) i'm getting the following exception:

[9/22/14 20:05:39:756 IDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O |E |20:05:39 |22 |admin | |com/jcraft/jsch/Session.setDaemonThread(Z)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/jcraft/jsch/Session.setDaemonThread(Z)V
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:225)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:96)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:103)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:81)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:65)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:693)
                at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:621)

There is no other jar of JSch with same class. the method exists.

what am i doing wrong? is there any setting that needs to be done in websphere?
it does load the Session class, it previously created it. just this method it does not see - in websphere 7.0.0.19

please advise

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the class Session already existed in some other Astrix jar
because of that , and because it was prior in load configuration, it was loaded before the proper Session class

only when searching the entire C drive using WinRar - it can search in archive properly - i searched for Session.Class and found it

then only left to remove the Astrix jar - that was not in use any how...